# Why can't my controller test find a JS template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails application I have a simple controller which also has an action with a JS view. During development mode I can access that view, but not during testing. During testing I get a "missing template" error.

I just can't figure out why this is happening. I'm posting the relevant parts, perhaps someone can 
help me with this.

**routes.rb**

```
resource :store, :controller => 'store' do    
  member do
    post :add_item
  end
end
```

**store_controller_test**

```
post :add_item, { :product_id => product.id }
```

**Exception message**

> ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template store/add_item

**Additional information:**

- The template file name is `add_item.js.erb`
- Other views from the same controller work both in testing and development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it can't find the template is because you are not creating a javascript post request in your tests, you are creating an HTML post request. To create a javascript post request, I would change the post call to specify the format.

```
post :add_item, { :product_id => product.id, :format => 'js' }
```